# facebook4j search public posts issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-java-api, facebook-java-sdk

I am using facebook4j to collect posts on a particular topic.
The code runs all find and I am able to search the topics. 
But the result also contains the irrelevant data. Example if i search a keyword such as "messi", i am expecting the posts that contains the word "messi". But the result contains the posts of a user whose name is "messi". How can i avoid this problem?

My code is as follows

```
Facebook facebook = FacebookFactory.getSingleton();
        facebook.setOAuthAppId("********", "*****************");
        facebook.getOAuthAppAccessToken();

ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.searchPosts("messi");
        for (Post result : results) {
            System.out.println("************");
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Comment: There's nothing you can do to influence the results. Also, be aware that the Public Post Search will be deprecated on April 30th, 2015.